# Cefsharp.wpf - rendering issue when application visibility is set to collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am having WPF app in which I am using Cefsharp.WPF - 73.1.130 package. In my app, I have one navigation panel on the right side which launched ng-app using the Chromium controller. After occurring one event at my WPF side, I am Expanding my panel, after expanding it launches the ng-app and again I am collapsing the right panel. The app loading is happening in the panel but at the moments its visibility is set to collapsed.
After happening a couple of such events on WPF side, my application get crashed.

Below is Event viewer log:
`Faulting application name: Some.exe, version: 192, time stamp: 0x5f08152d Faulting module name: libcef.dll, version: 73.1.13.0, time stamp: 0x5c8499d0 Exception code: 0x4000001f Fault offset: 0x01a29f95 Faulting process id: 0x2868 Faulting application start time: 0x01d656a37c65a770 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\some folder\some.exe Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\some folder\libcef.dll Report Id: 87b3b5b5-2630-45c7-a5f9-92a4b797d4d4 Faulting package full name:  Faulting package-relative application ID:`

I tried to handle app domain level exceptions in my app.xaml.cs like below but exception is not got caught there.

```
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += MyHandler;


        static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
        {
            Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
            Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Runtime terminating: {0}", args.IsTerminating);
            MessageBox.Show("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message + " ");
        }
```

I also tried to handle exception at cefsharp side like below

```
settings.UncaughtExceptionStackSize = 100;

_webBrowser.Value.RenderProcessMessageHandler = new RenderProcessMessageHandler();

class RenderProcessMessageHandler : IRenderProcessMessageHandler
    {
        public void OnUncaughtException(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, JavascriptException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnUncaughtException() - " + exception.Message);
            MessageBox.Show("Crashed - " + exception.Message);
        }


........
```

Can someone help, how to handle this rendering issue?

Comment: Version 73 is very old and unsupported. Try upgrading to version 84.

Comment: shifting from version 73 to the latest will be breaking changes and at this point of time, we cant do that.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to upgrade if you wish to fix this problem.

Comment: This is likely the relevant issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=983862